# how to infer a type when call static generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics, gson, static-methods

I am going through a problem when I call my generic static method, the type is not inferred. I don't have the type reference in the method arguments.

```
public static <K> K parseJsonToObject(String JsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    K k = gson.fromJson(JsonString, new TypeToken<K>() {
    }.getType());
    return k;
}
```

and calling with

```
homeContent = JsonHelper.<HomeContent>parseJsonToObject(result);
```

and got the crash log

```
illegal type variable reference
```

need some help here. thanks

Comment: If the type could be inferred like that, `TypeToken` wouldn't be necessary in the first place. You have to explicitly initialize it with the correct type. Or just pass a `Class` in your case.

Comment: thanks, i passed a class and it's working